# Promise and work thread chunking not working

Tags: javascript, worker

I have this in my code where i am using promise to limit at max MAX_WORKERS workgroup at a time.

```
 const MAX_WORKERS = 3;
 let promises = [];
 let chunk = 3;
  let totalNodes = keyCountMap.length / 2;
  let doneCount = 0;

  for (let m = 0; m < keyCountMap.length; ) {
    let remaining = totalNodes - doneCount;
    let numbWorker = Math.min(chunk, remaining);
    for (let i = 0; i < numbWorker; i++) {
      promises.push(createWorker(keyCountMap[m], keyCountMap[m + 1]));
      doneCount++;
      m += 2;
      console.log(doneCount);
      if (doneCount % MAX_WORKERS == 0) {
        Promise.all(promises).then((response) => {
          console.log("one chunk finish");
        });
      }
    }
  }
```

and createWorker function is:

```
function createWorker(data1, data2) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    let worker = new Worker();
    worker.onmessage = (event) => {
      postMessageRes = event.data;
      if (postMessageRes == 200) {
        worker.postMessage([
          nodePagesString,
          pagesString,
          copcString,
          data1,
          data2,
        ]);
      } else {
        workerCount += 1;
        let position = postMessageRes[0];
        let color = postMessageRes[1];
        for (let i = 0; i < position.length; i++) {
          positions.push(position[i]);
          colors.push(colors[i]);
        }
        if (workerCount == MAX_WORKERS) {
          worker.terminate();
          workerCount = 0;
          promises = [];
        }
        resolve(true);
      }
    };
  });
}
```

but the problem i have here is that it is not working like i wanted "3 work thread at a time and when it is done, spawn more thread/workers"

This is my console

[image]

and

[image]

which mean it is called at once and not after 3 threads which is count of chunks

Can anyone help me please on this

This is my worker code:

```
import { Copc, Key } from "copc";
import * as THREE from "three";
const color = new THREE.Color();
const colors = [];
let firstTime = true;
var nodePages, pages, receivedData, copc;
let x_min, y_min, z_min, x_max, y_max, z_max, width;
let positions = [];
let filename = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/data.entwine.io/millsite.copc.laz";

const readPoints = (id, getters) => {
  let returnPoint = getXyzi(id, getters);
  positions.push(
    returnPoint[0] - x_min - 0.5 * width,
    returnPoint[1] - y_min - 0.5 * width,
    returnPoint[2] - z_min - 0.5 * width
  );
  const vx = (returnPoint[3] / 65535) * 255;
  color.setRGB(vx, vx, vx);
  colors.push(color.r, color.g, color.b);
  firstTime = false;
};

function getXyzi(index, getters) {
  return getters.map((get) => get(index));
}

async function load() {
  // copc = await Copc.create(filename);
  // let scale = copc.header.scale[0];
  // [x_min, y_min, z_min, x_max, y_max, z_max] = copc.info.cube;
  // width = Math.abs(x_max - x_min);
  // // let center_x = (x_min + x_max) / 2;
  // // let center_y = (y_min + y_max) / 2;
  // // let center_z = (z_min + z_max) / 2;
  // receivedData = await Copc.loadHierarchyPage(
  //   filename,
  //   copc.info.rootHierarchyPage
  // );
  // nodePages = receivedData.nodes;
  // pages = receivedData.pages;
  postMessage(200);
}

async function loadData(nodes, pages, copc, myRoot, pointCount) {
  // console.log(copc, myRoot);
  const view = await Copc.loadPointDataView(filename, copc, myRoot);
  let getters = ["X", "Y", "Z", "Intensity"].map(view.getter);
  for (let j = 0; j < pointCount; j += 1) {
    readPoints(j, getters);
  }
  postMessage([positions, colors]);
}

load();

onmessage = function (message) {
  let nodePages = message.data[0];
  let nodes = JSON.parse(nodePages);
  let pagesStr = message.data[1];
  let pages = JSON.parse(pagesStr);
  let copcStr = message.data[2];
  let copc = JSON.parse(copcStr);

  let mapIndex = message.data[3];
  let pointCount = message.data[4];
  let myRoot = nodes[mapIndex];
  // console.log(mapIndex);
  loadData(nodes, pages, copc, myRoot, pointCount);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

What's creating the confusion here is the mix of synchronous and asynchronous processes. In your first code block there are two `for` loops that iterate over the `keyCountMap.length` and `numbWorker`, respectively. The inner `for` loop sets up an asynchronous callback once the array of promises are resolved. However, it does not wait for the result as it is asynchronous.

So, the behavior you're seeing is the looping over all values in the `for` loops and queueing of multiple async calls. You can read documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop) about how the event loop works.

The logging for the `doneCount` values happens first and then your async callbacks happen afterward. You should be able to verify this by changing the `console.log` within the Promise callback by adding the `doneCount` to it:

```js
/*
The use of JSON.parse and JSON.stringify is to preserve the initial value.
Otherwise it will show the current value of doneCount when the callback finalizes.
*/
console.log(`one chunk finish: ${JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(doneCount))}`);
```

**Edit** Added recommended adjustment.

```js
const chunkWorkers = async () => {
 const MAX_WORKERS = 3;
 let promises = [];
 let chunk = 3;
  let totalNodes = keyCountMap.length / 2;
  let doneCount = 0;

  for (let m = 0; m < keyCountMap.length; ) {
    let remaining = totalNodes - doneCount;
    let numbWorker = Math.min(chunk, remaining);
    for (let i = 0; i < numbWorker; i++) {
      promises.push(createWorker(keyCountMap[m], keyCountMap[m + 1]));
      doneCount++;
      m += 2;
      console.log(doneCount);
      if (doneCount % MAX_WORKERS == 0) {
        await Promise.all(promises).then((response) => {
          console.log(`one chunk finish: ${doneCount}`);
        });
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Hi thank you so much so you mean Promise.all () is asynchronous !! Is there any synchronous way where i can wait for it to finish before moving ahead

Comment: I believe so. If the first codeblock is set into a function and declared `async`, you can call `await` in front of the `Promise.all`. This will pause the looping until it responds. See an update to my answer. For this to work, some calling function would need to `await` it or with a Promise callback, e.g. `chunkWorkers .then(...)`

Comment: Hi thank you but still i am getting the memory issue, do you believe i am able to kill the memory used by worker properly ? because it looks like memory issue is there. Just for headup, I have added my worker code. Can you please check if there is memory leakage

Comment: I am doing woker.terminate() but do you think it is sufficient to terminate every thread

Comment: Yeah, I overlooked that. At this point, I'm not sure I have any other suggestions.

Comment: In the codeblock for your worker I see both `workerCount` and `promises` are referenced but not declared there. I'm not sure what's going on there but you may want to be careful about what context you are giving to each worker.